# Как сделать поиск аналогичный поиску на "github.com"?

Tags: c#, octokit.net

Используется - "octokit.net".
Меня интересует поиск по "repositories",  "users" и фильтрация результатов по языку.

**Сценарий:**
   1. Пользователь. Вводит поисковую фразу;
    2. Сайт. Выполняет поиск;
    3. Сайт. Выводит результат:
        a. repositories;
        b. users;
    Фильтр:
        - языки;

После нажатия кнопок "repositories" или "users" в таблицу выводится результат.
После нажатия кнопки языки (например "C#"), результаты фильтруются.

Общий результат поиска:
    **Репозитарии**
        - Репозитарии - 108 951 результатов
        - C# (репозитарий) - 4 315 результатов

```
**Пользователи**  
        - Пользователи  - ~ 4K результата   
        - C# (пользователи ) - ~ 72 результата
```

Как повторить данный сценарий работы поисковика?
Я написал предварительный код, но как сделать чтобы он работал более правильно не понимаю.

Метод не завершен "searchUser(string searchQuery_str)".
Я планирую сделать это по аналогии с «SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string  lang_str)»

Текущая логика кода:
    **- поиск по всем репозитариям:**
        - отправляем запрос;
        - получаем получаем ответ;
    **- поиск по репозитариям которые используют C#:**
        - отправляем запрос;
        - фильтруем запрос по языку "C#";
        - получаем ответ;

Т.е. сейчас выполняется для каждого случая отдельный запрос(var request), а мне кажется, что нужно выполнить один запрос, а потом выполнять над ним следующие действия:
  -  фильтровать;
  - сортировать;
  - очистить фильтрацию;
  - очистить сортировку.

Вопрос в том: как сделать чтобы можно было выполнить один запрос(var request), а потом выполнять над ним следующие действия:
  -  фильтровать;
  - сортировать;
  - очистить фильтрацию;
  - очистить сортировку;
  - вычислить количество результатов поиска?

Правильно ли я понимаю логику и возможно ли это сделать?

Если я правильно понимаю, то работа с поиском "пользователей"  будет аналогична с поиском "репозитариев".

Ссылка на документацию по поиску - [ссылка](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/search.md)
Ссылка на библиотеку octokit.net - [ссылка](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            // Получаем поисковую фразу
            string searchQuery_str = Search_txB.Text;
            string lang_str;
 
 
            // Поиск по репозитариям. "Результат"
            lang_str = "";
            var countRepo = await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str);
 
 
             label5.Text = countRepo;
 
            // Поиск по репозитариям. "Результат"
            lang_str = "C#";
            var countRepoLang = await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str);
 
            label7.Text = countRepoLang;
 
 }
 
 
public async Task<string> SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str)
 {
            // Поиск по "Реозитариям"
            var request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); // mvc client side framework - Структура клиентской стороны mvc           
 
            switch (lang_str)
            {
               case "C#":
                   request.Language = Language.CSharp;
                   break;                
            }
 
            var resultRepo = await client.Search.SearchRepo(request);
 
            // Количество репозитариев
            decimal countRepo_dec = Convert.ToDecimal(resultRepo.TotalCount);
 
            // Количество репозитариев. Форматирование
            string countRepo_str = formatValue(countRepo_dec);
 
            return countRepo_str;            
}
 
   // Поиск по "Пользователям" ()
public async void searchUser(string searchQuery_str)     
{        
            var request = new SearchUsersRequest(searchQuery_str); // _____
 
            var resultUser = await client.Search.SearchUsers(request);
 
            label6.Text = resultUser.TotalCount.ToString();
            // var resultUsers = await client.Search.SearchUsers(request);
}
```

Comment: Всмысле округление? Или сортировка? Или поиск?

Comment: @Ver Nick сам поиск... Прошу извинить, если вопрос размыт... Буду признателен, если подскажете как его более акцентировать...

Comment: А что такое вообще octokit.net ? Я искал, нету никаких объяснений. В ответе объяснил так, чтобы можно было именно на c# сделать. Если ответ не подходит я удалю.

Comment: @Ver Nick дополнил вопрос. Изучаю ваш ответ

Answer (score 0):

Используя функцию `sort()`, вы можете отсортировать репозитории, пользователей и все остальное по указанным в их категориях. Если категория такого-то проекта C#, вы `for`ом сравниваете их категории и, если категория равна той, что на кнопке, вы выводите.

Answer (score 0):

Изменил переменную `request`:
    - было "var" - стало `SearchRepositoriesRequest`;
    - было "локальной" - стало "глобальной";

Изменил метод `SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str)`
    - добавил аргумент "bool null_flg" - стало "SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str, bool null_flg)";
    - добавил проверку "bool null_flg";
      if (null_flg == false)
         {
             request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); 
         }

Код выглядит так

```
SearchRepositoriesRequest request;
    public async Task<string> SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str, bool null_flg)
            {
                //SearchRepositoriesRequest request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest();
                // Поиск по "Реозитариям"
                // if (request == null) // ошб
                if (null_flg == false)
                {
                     request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); // mvc client side framework - Структура клиентской стороны mvc           
                    // return request; 
                }

                switch (lang_str)
                {
                   case "C#":
                       request.Language = Language.CSharp;
                       break;                
                }

                var resultRepo = await client.Search.SearchRepo(request);

                // Количество репозитариев
                decimal countRepo_dec = Convert.ToDecimal(resultRepo.TotalCount);

                // Количество репозитариев. Форматирование
                string countRepo_str = formatValue(countRepo_dec);

                return countRepo_str;            
            }


    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Получаем поисковую фразу
                string searchQuery_str = Search_txB.Text;
                string lang_str;
                bool null_flg;


                // Поиск по репозитариям. "Результат"
                lang_str = "";
                null_flg = false;
                var countRepo = await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str, null_flg);
                null_flg = true;

                label5.Text = countRepo;

                // Поиск по репозитариям. "Результат"            
                lang_str = "C#";
                var countRepoLang = await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str, null_flg);

                label7.Text = countRepoLang;

            }
```

Будет ли это нормальным решением или можно сделать более грамотно?